# Вытащить данные между символами MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день!

Есть необходимость разбить строку на составляющие, а именно как вытащить номер телефона, следующий за запятой ('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666, и т.д')

Как это сделать?

Телефонов может быть как один, так и пятнадцать, и нужно вытащить все номера телефонов из максимально возможных после запятой))

Моя наработка:

```
 SELECT '8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666' as [All NUM]
        ,SUBSTRING('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666', 1, charindex(',', '8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666')-1) as [First NUM]
        ,SUBSTRING('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666', charindex(',', '8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666')+1, LEN('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666') - charindex(',', '8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666')) as [All after first NUM]
        ,right('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666',charindex(',',  SUBSTRING('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666', charindex(',', '8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666')+1, LEN('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666') - charindex(',', '8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666')))-2) as [Last NUM]
```

Answer (score 1):

Примените функцию SQL Server `string_split` - типа:

```
 SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('8555555555, 8999999999, 9166666666', ', ')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно более развернуто, но на сколько я понимаю, STRING_SPLIT преобразует данные в строки, а мне необходимо в столбцы. Или я не прав?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКозловский Столбцы же не удобно, как с ними потом работать, обращаться к каждому ведь в отдельности придется и надо не забывать, что все столбцы должны быть описаны в запросе, следовательно если вы и напишите в запросе 15 столбцов, что произойдет если в строке окажется 16 телефонов

Comment: @Mike, да, действительно, с одним столбцом попробую сделать, не подумал, что к каждому обращаться нужно будет) Спасибо!

Comment: У `STRING_SPLIT` второй аргумент односимвольный же.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   *
    ,ltrim(rtrim(substring(phone_nm, i2 + 1, i1 - i2 -1 ))) phone_nm_1
from (  select *
        ,charindex( ' ', x1.phone_nm + ' ', number ) i1
        ,case when number = 0 then 0 else charindex( ' ', x1.phone_nm + ' ', number - 1 ) end i2
    from t1 x1
    inner join master.dbo.spt_values x2
        on x2.type = 'P' and number between 0 and len( x1.phone_nm)
 ) x where i1 != i2
```

Решил вопрос иным способом.